# QUdpSocket::writeDatagram, wait for buffer free

Tags: qt

I'm using method QUdpSocket::writeDatagram and sending a lot of data. When the socket is full, the method return -1. Is it possible to do somethind like select() with a QUdpSocket?

```
while(!counterList.empty())
{
    CounterValuePtr value = counterList.dequeue();
    if (mUdpSocket->bytesToWrite() <= 1<<13)
    {
        const QByteArray datagram = toDatagram(*value);

        qint64 sentBytes = 0;
        try
        {
            sentBytes = mUdpSocket->writeDatagram(datagram, QHostAddress(mSettings->getConnectionIp()), mSettings->getConnectionPort());
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            emit dataLost();
            qWarning() << "Exception";
            throw;
        }

        qDebug() << datagram;
        if(sentBytes == -1)
        {
            QString errorMsg = getErrorMsg(WSAGetLastError());
            qWarning() << "SocketError (" << mUdpSocket->error() << ") : " << mUdpSocket->errorString() << ". " << errorMsg;
            emit dataLost();
        }
        else if(sentBytes < datagram.size())
        {
            qWarning() << "Not all data sent";
            emit dataLost();
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Counter "<< value->getName() << " sent";
            datasent = true;
            emit dataSent();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qWarning() << "Socket write buffer full. Dropping data.";
        emit dataLost();
    }
}
```

Some times, writeDatagram returns -1. When I print the last error with WSAGetLastError it prints the buffer is full.

Comment: Could you please add some code to clarify your question?

Comment: @peppe I've add the code to the question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? For example if you just want to wait for some data to be written use the bytesWritten() signal (or other signals). If you describe the behaviour you want then I am sure there is a Qt-like way of doing it...

Comment: You could use a [`QSocketNotifier`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html) to signal when the socket is ready to be written to.